# How can I make React append a number to a variable?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to automate fetching data from a source and assigning it to a variable that goes up by 1 each loop. Each call to the data source returns a different URL (of a picture of a cat, in this case).

```
            var i;
            var urlCount = 7;
            
            for (i=0; i < urlCount; i++) {
                this.setState({...this.state, isFetching: true});
                var response = await axios.get(USER_SERVICE_URL);
                this.image = response.data[0];
                url[i] = this.image.url;
                console.log([i] + url[i]);
            }
```

What I'm wanting it to do is create a list similar to the following:

- url0 = (url here),
- url1 = (another url here),
- url2 = (yet another url here),
- etc...

until the loop meets its condition. It works when I set the code to a manual value, like this:

```
    url0 = this.image.url;
    console.log([i] + url0);
```

But it doesn't work when I try to replace 0 with [i], as in the first example. It seems to be treating [i] as a property of url, instead of appending it *to* url. How can I make React append a number to a variable so that I can achieve the desired result above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would not recommend to do this with a for loop, also missing information about the component itself. Also using an object here as an example, but would recommend an array.

```js
// assuming a functional component
// add a state with a object (would rather go with an array)
const [urls, setUrls] = useState({});

// this should be within a function, better a useEffect with
// an async function defined inside and then called within the effect
var i;
var urlCount = 7;

// set fetching state
this.setState({ isFetching: true });

// loop (btw not recommended with async, better go with a map, return promises and then await Promise.all(yourArray))
for (i = 0; i < urlCount; i++) {
  var response = await axios.get(USER_SERVICE_URL);
  this.setState((oldState) => ({ ...oldState, [`url${i}`]: response.data[0] }));
}

// now you could access

const { url0, url1, url2... } = urls;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am using a class component right now. Would you recommend I rewrite it as a function component so that I can use Hooks?

Comment: Yes, absolutly. Writing functional components with hooks is pure joy. After some time you'll get used to it real quick and will never look back at class components :D

Answer (score -2):

**This is a suggestion or a tip rather than an answer**

The state variable `isFetching` is used like a flag. You are using the `setState` method before fetching the data.

Calling this method will re-render the component.

Also it is called in a for loop. So the component will re-render multiple times.

My suggestion is avoid setting state unnecessarily. It will re-render the components and cause unexpected behavior.

Try this code

```
var i;
var urlCount = 7;

//If you set state inside a for loop and urlCount is a large value
//your component will render many times unnecessarily
this.setState({...this.state, isFetching: true});
            
for (i=0; i < urlCount; i++) {
    var response = await axios.get(USER_SERVICE_URL);
    this.image = response.data[0];
    url[i] = this.image.url;
    console.log([i] + url[i]);
}
```

Comment: I got "TypeError: Cannot create property '0' on string ''
    at UserTableHOC.fetchUsersAsync" after trying that. Any ideas?

Comment: Why down vote ? It is not the right approach to call setState inside a for loop. It will re-render the component unnecessarily. I exactly pointed that out in my answer and asked the OP to use a property instead of state variable

Comment: @EmeraldTechno you should make similar changes in other parts of code too. Have you done that ?